# MYSQL JOIN two tables

Tags: mysql, join

We just want to make the query for mysql database, in which there are 12 table according to the months(JAN - DEC), with 32 Columns(JAN1, JAN2, JAN3,....JAN31). These database is used for getting the availability for hotel,like if we select a tour for three days (29JAN-1JAN), so the query will check the records for 2 tables, one for JAN and other for FEB. the whole columns stored the values in digit(like, 5,10,2,0,5,etc)its showing Rooms available. We are successfully built a query for single month, but we unable to create a mysql query for 2 months, because we want a value in greater than 1. like we only shows the available rooms only.

```
$num = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT id,table_type,JAN29,room_type FROM JAN Where table_type='disp' AND JAN!=0 ");
```

above query is working fine for me, we just want this query for 2 tables. and getting the positive value , greater than 0(1).

Please help to solve this problem ..

Thanks 
Rod

```
ID | JAN1 | JAN2 | JAN3 | JAN31|
34 | 5    | 3    | 3    | 4    |
56 | 4    | 3    | 9    | 3    |
28 | 0    | 7    | 0    | 9    |
```

Comment: SCNR ComicBookGuy would say: "worst db design ever".
You should also think ahead one more step... what do you do when you have to select 31.Dez to 2. Jan ?

Comment: I would suggest that you really need to reconsider this design.  You should replace your 12 tables and 360-odd columns with one table and one column.  SQL will be much easier and you won't need to create 12 new tables next year.

Comment: I don't believe the "above query is working fine" part, because in the same query you have `FROM JAN` which means `JAN` is a table, and `WHERE ... JAN != 0`, meaning `JAN` is a field.
And I agree 110% with @Rufinus about the design. Please, go back to the drawing board and start everything from scratch.

Comment: See we have so many data in these tables, and it connected with many functions ... Sorry to say .. but we can't able to change the any of the thing .

Comment: you could (not saying its the perfect way) redesign the DB, import the existing data and create views which represent the tables as they are now. so you gain time to adopt the other functions without breaking backward compatibily.

Comment: please view this code again , i have updated the changes...

Comment: I've to comment on this from perspective of me having to work with a system designed EXACTLY like this one - it's not a help comment, it's more of a warning comment. I am AMAZED how there are people who are being paid as programmers and they come up with such a design. It's absolutely terrible. It creates problems for people working ON the system and WITH the system. In my case - I had to import one such database into our own. It was a huge PITA. Please, educate your colleagues in proper relational design, please! And good luck getting your problem sorted.